# How do I opt-out of red dot on custom filters and questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, custom-filter

I have custom filters for questions with the tags I frequently use, but a red dot on them + a red dot on every new question that I haven't seen doesn't feel like a good UX (to me) and distracts me, so I just go there to get rid of the dot and takes the mood of checking questions and answering them.

[image]

I have to click on every filter twice or cycle between them (I have 2, but there may be people with 5, 10+ (?)) and sometimes I just go and click them to get rid of the distracting red dot and that's it! But that little task, takes my attention from what's important: *The questions*

Is there any way to opt-out of it? Or any script / something to remove it from my filters and the questions there?

Imagine a popular tag such as [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), I don't see the filter over night and the next morning: 50+ questions marked with a red dot, I know I can reload the page and all of them are cleared, but I can tell which questions I've visited and which not based on the hyperlink color, why do I need a second indicator?

[image]

<sub>Excuse the lack of handmade red-circle but it would look awkward to have one with a red dot inside.</sub>

---

Edit: To whoever asked to remove extensions, doesn't do anything

Comment: Only by using a user css style.

Comment: Hopefully someone will create it for us @rene :)