# New activity indicator has disappeared from questions on custom filters pages

Tags: bug, design, custom-filter, custom-questions-list

The "new question indicator" on custom filters pages seems to have disappeared.  This is the blue-filled disc that appears to the left of questions that the filter has not previously loaded.

[image]

The Custom Filters list on the main page shows that there are new questions (using the same blue-filled disc!), but when I click through to the question list page no questions are marked as new, even if they were not present the last time I loaded that page.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://imgur.com/a/fS8ft0A)? Because I'm still getting it.

Comment: @DialFrost No, the indicator right before a question

Comment: @DialFrost Hard to take a picture of something not there but [I did my best](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMlfn.png). And [here is what the indicator looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PVq7.png) which is still shown on the custom filter but not on the questions in the filer. EDIT: damn it, I made the red squares in the wrong place... the indicator shows immediately before the question title.

Comment: Edit window for the comment is up, so [here is a more accurate picture of what is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpG8a.png). I'll try to see if I have a screenshot with the indicator actually there. EDIT: [Screenshot with the actual indicator](https://i.imgur.com/Ix5KEMS.png)

Comment: @VLAZ Since was there supposed to be an indicator? I don't recall seeing any :/

Comment: @DialFrost it's been there for a year or more. Can't remember exactly when. It's only for custom filters, though - if you have a custom filter and there are new questions that match it, then opening the custom filter shows the indicator for the new questions only. There is no indicator for the questions you've already seen (more specifically, the ones that were present last time you opened the custom filter). Also, the indicator shows up when you open the filter. If you have it opened and do the in-page load of new questions, you won't get it. [Also used to be red](//i.imgur.com/78bhlNb.png)

Comment: [This Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389244/5320906) shows what it looked like in 2019 (when the indicator was red) @DialFrost.  I think it's been present since the custom filter feature was introduced in 2018/2019 , or shortly afterwards.

Comment: @snakecharmerb shortly afterwards. It wasn't present immediately, I do remember that, since I had a brief confusion when it showed up.

Comment: Also reported on MSE: [New activity indicator (bullet/dot) in Custom Filters no longer displaying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383520)

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ, and yes, this is a site-wide issue AFAIK.  The (I call it) "New activity" (since it isn't *just* for new questions), does not appear on Super User, Unix & Linux, or Ask Ubuntu for me.

Comment: I might not have looked around enough, but isn't there a bug tracking / ticket system somewhere? If so, could one nice person link to the relevant ticket, please? Without this indicators the filter's list becomes more or less useless for me.

Comment: @thebusybee there isn't a public one. The [status-*] tags usually indicate that a meta post is associated with a ticket on the internal tracking system. E.g., [status-review] for something that is created but unfinished and [status-complete] for items that resulted in some changes. However, there is no 1:1 link between [status-*] tags and the tracking system. Lack of tag may suggests it's not tracked but it's not a guarantee. *Adding* a [status-review] tag creates a ticket but it's only one-way relation - creating a ticket doesn't add tag.

Comment: Heck, no visible progress in over a year...

Comment: @thebusybee give it 6 to 8 years.